# Can not retrieve a WinTree in the code with foreach loop with codedui

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I can not iterate though a WinTree that took record. When I debug on childNodes I see some innerlist, lists on it but I can not get them in the code.

```
 #region Variable Declarations
 WinTree uITVTree = his.UIProMANAGEWindow.UIReportsWindow.UITVWindow.UITVTree;
 #endregion

 ITestControlCollection childNodes = uITVTree.Nodes;
```

none of the foreach loops below works, debugger does not go inside loops even though I tried with var

```
        foreach (var links in childNodes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(links.ToString());
        }

        foreach (UITestControl links in childNodes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(links.ToString());
        }

        foreach (WinTreeItem treeItem in childNodes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(treeItem.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If Wintree is not expanded, it will not get its child nodes.so just click on the tree once and then try the same code